# How to animate objects of a class from within another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, animation, tkinter

I'm using Python and `tkinter` to create a GUI. I've created two classes, `App` and `drawBall`. The `App` class inherits from `Tk.Frame`. I'm having trouble creating a `drawBall` object from within `App`.

I'd appreciate any other feedback about my code as well, I'm fairly new to OOP.

After creating the class `App`, which inherits from Tk.Frame. I'd like to create another class to draw a ball on the screen (using a canvas). I've created a base GUI, but when trying to call the class drawBall, I receive the following error: 'drawBall' object has no attribute 'canvas'.

```
class App(tk.Frame):

      def __init__(self,master):
          super().__init__(master)

        #create title and size for the window
           self.master.geometry("640x360")

           self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master,relief = 'raised',borderwidth = 1)
           self.canvas.grid(row = 0,column = 0,sticky = 'NW')



        #create a startSimulation button, place it in the bottom right corner
           self.startButton = tk.Button(self.master,text = 'Start',command = self.startCallback)
           self.startButton.grid(row = 2,column = 3)

        #create a quit button, place it in the bottom right corner
           self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.master,text = "Quit",command = self.master.destroy)
           self.quitButton.grid(row = 3, column =3)


    #callback for start button click
       def startCallback(self):
            #### this is where the error occurs #####
            self.ball1 = drawBall(self.master,self.canvas) 


class drawBall():
     def __init__(self,master,canvas):
         self.canvas.create_oval(25,75,35,85,fill = 'blue')


     def moveBall(self):
         deltaX = 1
         self.canvas.move(self.seed,deltaX,0)
         self.canvas.after(50,self.moveBall)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    window = tk.Tk()
    simulate = App(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

I'd hope that the call "self.ball1 = drawBall(self.master,self.canvas)" would result in the circle being drawn on the screen.

Comment: you forgot `self.canvas = canvas` in `drawBall`. And you don't need `master` in `drawBall`.

Comment: it is good rule to use noun as class name - ie. `class Ball` - and verb only for function name - (`def moveBall`). If your class is `Ball` then there is no reason to use name `Ball` in `moveBall` It will be easier to have different classes with  `move()` instead of `moveBall()`, `moveSquare()`, `moveSomethingElse()`. You may keep them on list and use `for item in list: item.move()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class `Ball`, that will take a `canvas`, and has the ability to move itself.
Then, in the `App`, you create a collection of balls, and order them to move.

something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.master.geometry("640x360")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, relief='raised', borderwidth=1)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NW')

        self.startButton = tk.Button(self.master, text='animate', command=self.launch_animation)
        self.startButton.grid(row=2, column=3)

        self.stopButton = tk.Button(self.master, text='stop', command=self.stop_animation)
        self.stopButton.grid(row=3, column=3)

        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.master, text="Quit",command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=4, column=3)

        self.balls = [Ball(self.canvas)]

        self.anim_is_on = False

    def stop_animation(self):
        self.anim_is_on = False

    def launch_animation(self):
        if self.anim_is_on:      # prevent launching several overlapping animation cycles
            return
        self.anim_is_on = True
        self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        if not self.anim_is_on:
            return
        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.moveball()
        self.after(100, self.animate)


class Ball():

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = self.canvas.create_oval(25, 75, 35, 85, fill='blue')

    def moveball(self):
        delta_x = 1
        self.canvas.move(self.id, delta_x, 0)


window = tk.Tk()
simulate = App(window)
window.mainloop()
```